# C programming sprinf issue

Tags: c

I'm using `sprintf` to print `int` variable which should display `1^2+2^2+3^2+4^2+5^2+6^2`. But my code only prints `1^2+6^2`. I don't know why the middle part is missing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* formatSeries(int n)
{
  char *tagstr = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*n*n);

  int pos = 0 ;
  int k;

  for (k = 1; k <= n; k++)
  {
    pos = sprintf(&tagstr[pos], "%d^2+", k);
  }
  tagstr[strlen(tagstr) - 1] = '\0';

  return tagstr;
}

 void main()
{
  int n = 6;
  printf("%s \n", formatSeries(n));
}
```

Comment: s/`pos = sprintf`/`pos += sprintf`?

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: Yep - @a3f has it.  Also this line `tagstr[strlen(tagstr) - 1] = '\0';` is....wrong...as well as unnecessary.  Also the initial size of your array is not big enough until about n=4

Comment: Also, why is your loop going from 1 to n instead of 0 to n-1?

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll probably for printing only. :)

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll because the values being printed warrant it. It has nothing to do with indexing.

Comment: @LoztInSpace that line has purpose (trim the last `+` from the string), but it could be better done with simply `tagstr[pos-1] = 0;` once the fix from a3f is deployed.

Comment: @WhozCraig Ah yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main issues in your code; the one - as already mentioned in the comments - is that you do not increase `pos` but reassign it again and again with (almost) the same value. Hence, after the first iteration, you will constantly write to a position at `4` (or `5` if `k` would become >=10 and the numbers would thereby get more digits),

Second, your `malloc` will not work for small `k`s, since each string like `"+1^2"` takes at least 4 characters; so if you size the buffer with `n * n`,  then the buffer will be too small if `n` is <= 3, and (probably much) too big if `n` becomes larger.

I'd suggest to assume a maximum range of `n` (let's say up to 7 digits) and dimension the buffer accordingly.

A minor thing (and not essential) is that you probably could avoid writing superfluous `+` at all in that you use a different format string for the first iteration; just do show the idea, really not essential:

```
char* formatSeries(int n)
{
    const size_t maxSize = n * (7+3) + 1;

    char *tagstr = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*maxSize);

    int pos = 0 ;
    int k;
    for (k = 1; k <= n; k++)
    {
        const char* formatStr = (k==1) ? "%d^2" : "+%d^2";
        pos += sprintf(&tagstr[pos], formatStr, k);

    }
    return tagstr;
}
```